# Civilization 4 Team Victory conditions

Tags: civilization-4

**How are the conditions of a team victory calculated?**

It is clear that when playing a Team game of Civilization 4, teams win or lose together as a team.  However, it is not clear how the target goals of these conditions are calculated, and it can be very time-consuming to attempt to determine this.  Is a cultural victory triggered when the requisite number of legendary culture cities are achieved between all team members combined, or must they all belong to a single player?  Do Civilizations on a team build their own collective Space Ship, or each build one separately?  Are players voted for regarding Diplomatic victories collectively or separately?  Please be specific - it's possible each type of victory may have a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've played Civ 4, but if I remember correctly:

In Team Play, all victory conditions should be shared across all players on the team.

If you're playing for a Space Victory, all parts completed will contribute to a single Space Ship, meaning each player can work on constructing different parts of the ship at once and once all parts are completed between the number of team members, the victory conditions should be met.

Cultural Victory should also be all Culture Cities combined on a team.

I honestly can't remember much about the diplomatic victories so I will not speak towards that, but given the trend it would be safe to say that what ever the conditions, they would be shared across all team members.

Comment: Your answer would be good, but you sound unsure.  Can you confirm it with facts or evidence?

Comment: @SouthpawHare Nope, just personal experience and word of mouth. Double checked these with a friend of mine who played a lot more Civ 4 then I did and he agreed that this is how it worked. Sorry bud, that's everything I've got. =P